# Is there something like UITextView for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, watchkit

I need to display quite a bit of text and the only option I see is `WKLabel`. There are only about three screens worth of text so it isn't too big. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `WKInterfaceLabel` set the lines property to '0' and set the height to `Size To Fit Content` in your storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `WKLabel`. 
If you want your user to write something, use  `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions`.

Answer (score 1):

Text and labels from [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html)

WatchKit provides a standard modal interface for retrieving text input from the user. When presented, the interface allows the user to enter text via dictation or to select from a standard set of phrases or emoji.

[image]